# Animation Problems in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

I've got few problems in using animation in android studios:

1. I'm trying to translate certain images at an angle. Like in the image below I want to move that attachment pin like icons to all the ends of the corner. How can I do this?

[image]

2. I was trying to scale up the image of the gear image in the center every time its tapped and scale down when tapped again. However, the image starts losing its quality. How can I prevent the quality from getting deteriorated?

[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.rootonelabs.vicky.pulse;

import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.gigamole.library.PulseView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    PulseView pulseView;
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    ImageView gear;
    ImageView icon1,icon2,icon3,icon4,icon5,icon6;
    int chkClick = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pulseView = (PulseView)findViewById(R.id.pv);
        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pulseView.startPulse();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pulseView.finishPulse();
            }
        });

        gear = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gear);

        gear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gear.animate().scaleX(1.5f).scaleY(1.5f).setDuration(500);
                animateDiagonalPan();
                icon1 = findViewById(R.id.icon1);
                icon1.animate().translationXBy(120).translationYBy(120).setDuration(500);
                if(chkClick==0)
                {
                    pulseView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500);
                    gear.animate().scaleX(1.5f).scaleY(1.5f).setDuration(500);
                    pulseView.finishPulse();
                    chkClick = 1;
                }else{
                    pulseView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500);
                    gear.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(500);
                    pulseView.startPulse();
                    chkClick = 0;

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f39c12"
    tools:context="com.rootonelabs.vicky.pulse.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="START"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStop"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/men3"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_archive"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_black_24dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_archive"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_black_24dp"/>

    <com.gigamole.library.PulseView
        android:id="@+id/pv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:pv_alpha="70"
        app:pv_color="#FFF"
        app:pv_icon="@drawable/men2"
        app:pv_icon_width="100dp"
        app:pv_icon_height="100dp"
        app:pv_interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        app:pv_measure="height"
        app:pv_spawn_period="1000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: animation? what animation? whats your code?

Comment: @pskink added the code

Comment: I would suggest you get the image as in largest scale, then animate to scale down the image. This would ensure that the image is not losing its quality as you are not stretching the image, but make it smaller and return to its original size.

Comment: These are really two questions. You should probably make two posts out of it.